# jQuery: Detect focus of a input filed and show a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a password field with this HTML mark up:

```
<div class="password-message">Password must contain at least 8 characters. At least 1 number, 1 upper case, and 1 lower case letter.</div>
<input type="password" class="required" id="password" name="Password" constraint="password" trackerror="true" placeholder="Create Password">
```

I have jquery that reads the password length and when its > 1 it shows the tooltip with class password message.

```
       if( password.length >= 1 ){
            $('.password-message').slideDown(500, function(){
                $(this).css('overflow', 'visible');
            });
        }
```

I want to change this a little.  When the password field is clicked (is in focus) I want to show the tooltip.

This is the jquery I came up with.

```
        $( "#password").focus(function() {
            alert("Focussed");
            $('.password-message').slideDown(500, function(){
                $(this).css('overflow', 'visible');
            });
        });
```

This doesn't work the way I want. I get the alert message not when I click in the field but after U type a few characters. Is there a way I can fix it. I have the CSS working, I need to figure out a way to use jQuery focus function and then integrate with my existign code.

Comment: I get the alert when I click in the field: http://jsfiddle.net/njfct1ef/

Comment: It's working for me too: http://jsfiddle.net/g9p0rzqa/ Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Thanks you both. For some reason, on my page, the tool tip shows up on focus only when the there is atvleast one charecter in the field. Strange, Not sure why that is happening.

Comment: Nevermind. The code chunk was wrapped in   $('.trialForm #password').on('keyup', function(){ }. I have the same chunk of code outside the key up function and it works fine now